# location tracking using wifi

Tags: android, location, wifi

I want to make location tracking app in android.
But I will use my app in subway or building.
I think gps system does not work.
So using wifi is better than gps.
Please let me know how to using wifi in android.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

when you are connected to WIFI then simply use NETWORK PROVIDER for your location updates.

locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);